# jQuery animate left not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.1.103/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.1.103/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.1.103/wordpress/wp-content/themes/magazine-pro/js/entry-date.js?ver=1.0.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.1.103/wordpress/wp-content/themes/magazine-pro/js/responsive-menu.js?ver=1.0.0'></script>

<div class="site-container">
<nav class="nav-primary">
<div class="responsive-menu-icon">
</div>
<div class="genesis-nav-menu">
</div>
</nav>
</div>
```

In responsive-menu.js

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

    $(".nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu").addClass("responsive-menu").before('<div id="responsive-menu-icon"></div>');


    $("#responsive-menu-icon").click(function(){

        $(".site-container").animate({left:'200px'}, 400, 'easeOutBack');
        //$("nav .genesis-nav-menu").animate({width: 'toggle'});

    });
});
```

For my CSS, I have:

```
.nav-primary .responsive-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;  
    left: 0; 
    }

.nav-primary #responsive-menu-icon {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.site-container
{
    overflow: hidden;  
    position: relative;  
    z-index: 2;
    display:block;
}
```

But, when I click ont he button, nothing happens. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.....

Comment: replace **class** with **id** for the div like : **<div id="responsive-menu-icon"></div>** and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
$(".nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu").addClass("responsive-menu").before('<div id="responsive-menu-icon"></div>');
```

to:

```
$(".nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu").addClass("responsive-menu").before('<div class="responsive-menu-icon"></div>');
```

since you've assigned `<div class="responsive-menu-icon">` not `<div id="responsive-menu-icon">`

or you can change `<div class="responsive-menu-icon">` to `<div id="responsive-menu-icon">` in your HTML markup

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Changed it but it still does not work.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to replicate your problem?